Can i just say "may I?"
If I see somebody carrying a lot of bags and I want to help, can I just say "may I?"
will it sound natural to english speakers?

it would make more sense to say would you like some help? or may I help you?

To sound more friendly "Do you need a hand (carrying the shopping)?"

I believe with the body language gesturing to help, you should be understood with just May I? to mean you are offering to help.
Edit2
This was used more commonly in say 1955 by a British upperclass or middleclass person.

You might say this if you were British upper or middle class, and it was 1955.

Thanks, @Michael Harvey.  I've added this point.

Wait! M. Harvey's comment was suggesting that "May I" would likely to have been said by someone highly educated or wealthy in Britain in the 1950s. Your edit suggests that it would be used to talk to someone in that era and belong to  those two  classes. Thank God this nonsense with social class is dead and buried.

Thanks, @Mari-Lou A.  I've edited my answer.

@Mari-LouA - 'this nonsense with social class is dead and buried' - where on earth did you get that idea? It's alive and kicking where I am.

Oh come on, it's nothing like it used to be. Don't you hear the myriad of dialects? Northerners, and youngsters with working class background are BBC radio DJ's, TV presenters, doctors, architects, IT specialists, developers, musicians, artists, and actors,  (although that last category seems to be still dominated by RADA graduates). But if you're thinking of the world of politics and managerial positions (CEOs etc.)  the upperclass still have a stronghold there.

@Mari-LouA - this could be the basis for a very long discussion, but not here. I agree that the Britain of today is, overall, much less deferential than it used to be decades ago, and I am heartily glad of that, but I feel we still have a very long way to go. As for politicians and CEOs, I think the middle class has the upper hand there (and may has had since Disraeli?). Consider, though, Angela Rayner (of whom I am a huge fan).

@Mari-LouA - it seems to me that there still is a class system, just that the entrance criteria for the upper echelons have changed, and money gets you where noble birth used to.

@MichaelHarvey in which part of the world is money considered a handicap?! Like you said, we could talk for hours about the British class system, it's a fascinating subject but completely off-topic here.
